# How to find out if a coroutine job is delayed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there an elegant way to find out if a job is currenty `delay`ed?

I need to restart a job, but only if it is being delayed, like this

```
fun restart() {
    if (job?.isDelayed()) job?.cancel()
    else return
    job = launch {
        repeat(10) {
            //do some heavy work
            delay(5000)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share what is your use scenario?

Comment: On Android I need to preload a video (the heavy work) with a backoff retry strategy (the repeat block). When user requests to show the video but preloading had failed and is being delayed, it should restart immediately. Definitely one could use some flags to control this, but was wondering if there is some kotlin approach for this.

Comment: For me it doesn't sound like something that should be built utilizing the coroutines delay functionality. You should create your own abstraction on top of it. Anyway, I don't think this is even technically possible. There is (almost) nothing special about the delayed coroutine, it is pretty much a suspended coroutine with some kind of a timer to resume it. We can create our own implementation of `delay()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found from the Job documentation, there is no Delay state for Job. There are several states of *New*, *Active*, *Completing*, *Cancelling*, *Cancelled*, *Completed* in the job, and the state flow provided by the job also flows in these states.

It seems that it is impossible to judge whether it is in the delay state from the Job alone. We can set the delay flag in the class separately to change the state before/after the delay function call. The following is my test code, I hope it can help you.

```kotlin
object Test {

     private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())

     private var job: Job? = null

     private var delayFlag = false

     fun startJob() {
         if (job?.isActive == true) return
         job = scope. launch {
             repeat(10) {
                 delayFlag = true
                 delay(5000)
                 delayFlag = false
             }
         }
     }

     fun restart() {
         if (job?.isActive == true && delayFlag) job?.cancel() else return
         println("restart job")
         job = scope. launch {
             repeat(10) {
                 //do some heavy work
                 delayFlag = true
                 delay(5000)
                 delayFlag = false
             }
         }
     }



}

fun main() = runBlocking {
     Test. startJob()
     repeat(5) {
         Test. restart()
         delay(20000L)
     }
}
```